# Typewriter Animation Using the 'Animate' Package

Tags: animate

I wanted to do something similar like here:

[Improving typewriter animation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/improving-typewriter-animation)

But using the `animate` package. I managed to get a very poor solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{animateinline}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fboxsep1mm
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
    % one frame per second
    $\phantom{\text{Alles Gute zum Geburtstag!}}$
    \newframe   
    $\text{Alles}\phantom{\text{ Gute zum Geburtstag!}}$
    \newframe       
    $\text{Alles Gute}\phantom{\text{ zum Geburtstag!}}$
    \newframe       
    $\text{Alles Gute zum}\phantom{\text{ Geburtstag!}}$
    \newframe   
    $\text{Alles Gute zum Geburtstag}\phantom{\text{!}}$
    \newframe   
    $\text{Alles Gute zum Geburtstag!}\phantom{\text{}}$                    
    \end{animateinline}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The **`\phantom`** is in my experience needed to **reserve** in all frames the same **space**. **Otherwise** the text gets **distorted**.

Here is the result:

http://www.bipede.de/Downloads/HB.pdf

Has someone an idea how to get the very cool solution in

[Improving typewriter animation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/improving-typewriter-animation)

to work here?

By the way, `Alles Gute zum Geburtstag` means `Happy Birthday` in German.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Character for character

The usage of the `xstring` macros is taken from [the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63255/improving-typewriter-animation).

The width of the text (in `\Huge` style) is saved to `\mytextwidth`.
As `\StrLen` counts from `0` to, in this case, `27`, `\multiframe` needs to animate `28` frames, which is why `\mylen+1` is calculated and saved to `\frames`.

This example uses the `\multiframe` macro because we can use variables (the other question used `PGF`'s `\foreach` for this) and don't need to type every frame individually.

The `\vphantom` is needed because we start with no text (`\icounter=0`) and we need vertical height for. If you want to start with `A` use `icounter=1+1` and re-replace `\frames` with `\mylen` in the `\multiframe` command.

`\makebox` makes everytime a box of the full text's width so that `animate` doesn't stretch the text. (We could have used also `\StrRight`, but this needs less calculation.)

### Code (char for char)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{animateinline}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\mytext{Alles Gute zum Geburtstag!}
\StrLen{\mytext}[\mylen]
\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{\widthof{\Huge\mytext}}
\def\frames{\number\numexpr\mylen+1\relax} % \frames = \mylen + 1

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
  \multiframe{\frames}{icounter=0+1}{
    \makebox[\mytextwidth][l]{\Huge\vphantom{\mytext}\StrLeft{\mytext}{\icounter}}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Looks a lot like … (a.k.a. Output)

[image]

## Word for word

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{animateinline}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\mytext{Alles Gute zum Geburtstag!}
\StrCount{\mytext}{ }[\countSpaces]
\newlength{\mytextwidth}
\setlength{\mytextwidth}{\widthof{\Huge\mytext}}
\def\frames{\number\numexpr\countSpaces+2\relax} % \frames = \countSpaces + 2

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{2}
  \multiframe{\frames}{icounter=0+1,icounterr=1+1}{%
    \makebox[\mytextwidth][l]{%
      \Huge\vphantom{\mytext}%
      \ifnum\icounter=0\relax\else
        \ifnum\icounterr=\frames\relax\mytext\else%
          \StrBefore[\icounter]{\mytext}{ }%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I was at work, therefore the late reply.

Comment: Is it possible show the last frame (complete message) of the animation if the animation fails (either because the viewer --like Evince-- does not show the animation or because something is disabled in Acrobat)?