# Turn a LateX generated text into something animated

Tags: packages, animations, animate, video

I would like to make videos about mathematics, where the formulas are written instead of just shown. The classical way of doing this is like [khanAcademy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5myJ8dg_rM).

The thing I don't like about this is the fact that you really have to write it down, I would like to be able to get the same effect using LaTeX. I.e. I would first make my LaTeX slide completely and then I would like to turn into a video how this is created. Preferably each letter, each sign,... should be written individually as if I were writing it myself.

Is there a package in LaTeX or some online tool which enables me to do this?

An example of something that looks like this is [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)! When I write a LaTeX formula in it, it generates the text I'm typing real time, I could record this and use recording to cut out the part where the text is generated, I could then paste this GIF into the video I work on. Two things I don't like about using this:

- It's really not meant to be used that way and thus it takes a long time to make a video like that.
- All text (and formula's) you type appear as you type it, but it's not really written, it just appears all at once, I would like each letter to really appear as if it was being written.

Comment: Probably OT for us, but there are tools used to turn text into 'writing animations' which I suspect simply use the finished paths: we have something like that at work to make 'interesting' slide videos.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but: What is OT?

Comment: 'Off Topic': The tools I've seen in this area don't use LaTeX, perhaps (?) working from PDFs or similar.

Comment: Then which forum should I turn to? Or which tools are you talking about, they might solve my problem

Comment: Look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81835

Comment: It's certainly a step in the good direction, but letters still just appear which is a bit of a shame, but I guess it might not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I've created the python script that can do just that.
At the moment I'm developing a c++ app that allows to generate any latex formula in a hand writing style (as a sequence of png frames). Later on, I'll try it to convert to PremierePro plugin.

Here are the results:
https://youtu.be/upfh13N9SOc?t=12

Yaroslav.

Comment: As long as you don't show us your script, it  doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: It doesn't, of course. My comment is just to notify people that there is some progress in the subject. My "answer" should be relocated to comment section.

Comment: Once it is ready, will you make your script public? That would be useful, I think.

Comment: The c++ code is almost trivial. But it took 3 years of hand work in evenings to modify a half of latex fonts to make them animated. One more half to go. I'll try to use neural networks to complete the job. Due to this, I guess, it will be a commercial project.

Comment: Oh my, good luck!