# Writing animation in LaTeX

Tags: animations

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81850/32576) answer, one can find code for a typewriter animation. I was wondering if one could go a step further, and animate text/mathematics in LaTeX stroke-by-stroke. In other words, I want the text to appear as if it's being written by a human, continuously.

Any ideas on how to do this with text and/or mathematical symbols (preferably in the standard fonts) are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Drawing is something different than using fonts. A font's character is something that you can use as a whole thing and have not internal functionality that splits  it in parts to show them in frames as continuously drawn. This means, that you have to hide smaller and smaller part of each letter (through a "tikz clip" or something) until the whole character will appear. And my conclusion is that: Every character for every font that you want to animate, has to be animated separately and with a clever way that will allow fontsize scaling.

Comment: There are projects that allow you to animate a particular font (a particular project we are working on, if popular, will allow you to animate most latex fonts) and insert it as a png sequence with transparent background in to a video file.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvL-ZqG5aVo