# A small tool to simplify the units of measurement using siunitx package

Tags: siunitx, automation, animate

Considering that some of my students, especially first year students (14 years old) are not able to simplify units of measure and find the final unit of measure, is it possible to create an automatic tool simplification with `siunitx` package (with animation bar, forward, backward, pause, etc.)?

For example:

```
kg × N/kg = kg ; W × s = J
```

I have not any idea.

Comment: Hello, my friend. Are you aware of the `animate` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/animate)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Hi, mister :-) ahah...I never have used animate package with a lot of sincerity. You can see also my profile (question and answer) and I never have put a question or an answer. But I know that exist the package.

Comment: I am too busy at the moment but maybe this is inspiration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81835. Just add `controls` to the options `[autoplay ,loop]` and you see what I mean. Maybe somebody else can provide a complete answer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I with the head are burned :-(

Comment: FYI: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Version

---

This is just quick and dirty, sorry, I am too busy today. I hope a real pro can take it from here. View in **Adobe Reader**!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

    \begin{animateinline}[controls]{2} % The "2" controls the speed. Othe options are "autoplay" or "loop".
      % First frame
      \makebox[20mm][l]{kg x N/kg} % makebox to reserve space
    \newframe   
      % Second Frame
      \makebox[20mm][l]{kg}                   
    \end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

### Update 1

---

Hi! I added some more examples, again, view in **Adobe Reader**! An "issue" is that you have to make sure that the first frame reserves the right amount of space. Therefore I use `\strut` but this is not always enough. Alternatively, you can use `\vphantom`, see the **linked question/answer in the code** for a more detailed explanation.

As you can tell from my code, I do not hold a [CS degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) :). This is a rather *manual* approach (hence my first name: *Manuel* :)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81835 for more details.
\begin{document}

\section*{Example 1}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls, step]{2}
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 1: kg x N/kg}
    \newframe   
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 2: \bcancel{kg} x N/\bcancel{kg} = N}         
    \newframe   
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 3: N}        
    \end{animateinline}
  
\section*{Example 2}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls, step]{2}
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 1: W x s}
    \newframe   
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 2: W x s = J}                 
    \end{animateinline}  
    
\section*{Example 3 (\texttt{siunitx} and \texttt{xfrac, sfrac})}
    \begin{animateinline}[controls, step]{2}
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 1: $\si{kg}\times \sfrac{\si{\newton}}{\si{\kilo\gram}}$}
    \newframe   
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 2: $\bcancel{\si{\kilo\gram}}\times \sfrac{\si{\newton}}{\bcancel{\si{\kilo\gram}}}$} 
    \newframe   
      \makebox[40mm][l]{\strut Step 3: $\si{\newton}$}          
    \end{animateinline}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much...always...but the animation start? :-))))))

Comment: @Sebastiano There are several options, for example replace `[controls]` with `[controls, autoplay,loop]`.

Comment: I'm scarce :-((( sigh sigh.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have to go offline now. Will be back tomorrow. Bye.

Comment: I'm going to bed too and thank you so much. Good night.

Comment: Perfect. Thus I have an idea. My best regards.

Comment: I am happy to hear that!